# Sum all expenses of a given type given a list of expense types in a separate sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, worksheet-function

I use Google Sheets to keep track of my expenses. The file currently consists of:

- `Sheet 1`: "Expense Types"
- `Sheet 2`: "2015 Details".

The first column of `Sheet 1` contains the list of admissible expense types, and each row in `Sheet 2` details one single expense: data, notes, type and amount.

I would like to create a new `Sheet 3`: "2015 Summary" that would contain, on each row, a single expense type and the sum of all expenses of the given type. Moreover, I want this sheet to automatically update in case I add a new expense type on `Sheet 1`.

Is it possible to do this using worksheet formulas or do I need to do some scripting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pivot table to do that.   Choose **Data > Pivot** from the menus, and follow the prompts to set it up.

There's an example of something similar here:   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VIeA4zAjID0y1jo1FnsbfGA4qmpRgAxMykLXi1pOfhc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to set up Sheet 2 so that it automatically reads from Sheet 1.   (If you don't do this, then there is not point in having sheet 2.)

Comment: Yes, Sheets 2 and 3 could operate completely independently.   But this would not be a smart way to have a spreadsheet set up.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for the `SUMIF` function. An example is illustrated below:

[image: SUMIF Example]

Comment: This isn't done using a pivot table, these are just cells. To reference other sheets, you would use the `'SheetName'!A1` syntax.